# Why is Azure Pipelines Docker task buildContext empty?

Tags: docker, azure-pipelines

I'm running a pipeline and cannot figure out why the buildContext in the Docker task is empty even though the cmd script clearly shows that the directory is not?

The tasks in my `azure-pipelines.yml` are as follows:

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: './services/UI.Web'
    script: 'dir'

- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    containerRegistry: 'docker'
    repository: 'username/repository'
    Tags: tag
    Dockerfile: './services/UI.Web/Dockerfile'
    buildContext: './services/UI.Web'
```

The output in the pipeline logs are as follows:

```
Directory of D:\a\1\s\services\UI.Web

... list of files and folders ...

10 File(s) 18 Dir(s) 179,798 bytes
```

and

```
"C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe" build -f D:\a\1\s\services\UI.Web\Dockerfile -t username/repository:tag D:\a\1\s\services\UI.Web
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
```

If I change the `buildContext` to `'./services'` then the log output changes to

```
"C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe" build -f d:\a\1\s\services\UI.Web\Dockerfile -t username/repository:tag d:\a\1\s\services
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.701GB
```

Comment: I think the build context is a glob. You might try `buildContext: './services/UI.Web/**'`

Comment: @DanielHabenicht, that doesn't seem to work, the console logs the following error: `unable to prepare context: path "D:\\a\\1\\s\\services\\UI.Web\\**" not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure you don't have a [.dockerignore](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) file with a
   solitary `*`.
2. Make sure you've done 1

Such a rookie mistake so hopefully this can save other people the hours it took me to figure it out.